# How does Linux kernel handle double click event for a PS/2 mouse in mousedev.c

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I am trying to understand how Linux kernel handles the mouse interrupts in detail.

I was able to trace out the flow starting from the interrupt in i8042.c to an event in mousedev.c. 
In the function mousedev_key_event() in [line#230 mousedev.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/input/mousedev.c#L230) for Linux kernel 3.6,
I see that button events are decoded. But I am curious to see how is a double click event handled.

I tried looking for a time interval in which the second click has to be detected. I did find one for touchpad which is "tap_time" defined in the same file [line#51](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/input/mousedev.c#L51), but not for an external PS/2 mouse. Can someone help me figure it?

Comment: Surely it's up to the client app, such as GPM, to handle console double clicks?

Comment: Well, is it that the GPM implements the double click logic for an external mouse and that the linux kernel just reports the single click events?